# define a herf link based on if/else scenario in JS file

Tags: javascript, html

So basically I'm a beginner in JavaScript and HTML and trying to play with functions call on JS that will edit my HTML file.
Now, I'm trying to redirect users to different pages based on their type.
I want to use "onload" function in order to determine the user type and edit the link according to the result.

HTML:

```
<body onload="what_user()">
<div id="result">zone</div>
</body>
```

JS file:

```
function what_user() {
    var d = document.getElementById("result");
    var user = ""; // get the user type
    if (user == "") d.outerHTML = "<a href=" + "admin_index.html" + ">" + "</a>";
    else d.outerHTML = "<a href=" + "admin_user.html" + ">" + "</a>";
}
```

I have some problems understanding how to call a function from HTML and use it on JS as well as return values.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: `if (user = "")` - that is an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: I agree with @CBroe. Try `==` instead

Comment: `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<a href="...` makes little sense - the element you are working on here _is_ the link already, so by assigning this kind of innerHTML data, you would be _nesting_ a link into a link (which is not allowed to begin with.) Either set `outerHTML`, or manipulate `href` attribute and text content inside the link separately.

Comment: @CBroe tried to use outerHTML instead. still not working.

Comment: It _is_ working, but you gave the link no actual text content now, so you don't _see_ anything in the rendered result. But if you inspect this using your browser dev tools, you will see that the link itself is actually there in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't play with elements as string. Create an element and put it where you want.

```js
function what_user() {
  var d = document.getElementById("result");
  let a = document.createElement('a')
  a.text = 'zone'
  var user = ""; // get the user type
  if (user == "") a.href = 'admin_index.html'
  else {
    a.href = 'admin_user.html'
  }
  d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
  document.body.appendChild(a)
}
```

```html
<body onload="what_user()">
  <div id="result">zone</div>
</body>
```